# Fluid colorchange of an svg in different sections

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I am trying to change the color of a SVG according  to its current section background ...its working with shapes but as soon as i change it to a path it will jump the colors instead of fluid change...why is that?

**This is what i want to achieve (fluid transition of colors)**

```js
var sections = document.querySelectorAll('section');
var logo = document.querySelector('#logo');
var nextColor = document.querySelector('#nextColor');
var currentColor = document.querySelector('#currentColor');
var initialHeight = logo.clientHeight;
var lastScrollPosition = 0;

// Set current section color
sections.forEach(function (section) {
  var top = section.offsetTop - window.pageYOffset;
  if (top <= logo.offsetTop && (top + section.clientHeight) >= logo.offsetTop) {
    currentColor.setAttribute('fill', section.dataset.color);
  }
});

window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
  sections.forEach(function (section) {
    var top = section.offsetTop - window.pageYOffset;
    var offset = top - logo.offsetTop;
    
    // If the top edge of the section is behind the logo
    if (top <= logo.offsetTop) {
      // Make sure the section color has its initial height
      currentColor.setAttribute('height', initialHeight);
      // If the logo is still inside the section, fill it with the section color
      var bottom = top + section.clientHeight;
      if (bottom >= logo.offsetTop) {
        currentColor.setAttribute('fill', section.dataset.color);
      }
      
      return;
    }
    
    // If logo collides with the lower section
    if (offset <= logo.clientHeight) {
      nextColor.setAttribute('fill', section.dataset.color);
      currentColor.setAttribute('height', offset);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#logo {
  position: fixed;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: -50px;
}

section {
  height: 100vh
}

#dark {
  background-color: #2a2a2a;
}
```

```html
<div id="logo">
  <svg height="100" width="100">
    <rect id="nextColor" width="100" height="100"/>
    <rect id="currentColor" y="0" width="100" height="100"/>
  </svg>
</div>

<div class="sections">
  <section data-color="#000000" id="light"></section>
  <section data-color="#ffffff" id="dark"></section>
  <section data-color="#cccccc" id="light2"></section>
</div>
```

**This is what i got but its not transitioning smoothly like the working example above:**

```js
var sections = document.querySelectorAll('section');
var logo = document.querySelector('#logo');
var nextColor = document.querySelector('#nextColor');
var currentColor = document.querySelector('#currentColor');
var initialHeight = logo.clientHeight;
var lastScrollPosition = 0;

// Set current section color
sections.forEach(function (section) {
  var top = section.offsetTop - window.pageYOffset;
  if (top <= logo.offsetTop && (top + section.clientHeight) >= logo.offsetTop) {
    currentColor.setAttribute('fill', section.dataset.color);
  }
});

window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
  sections.forEach(function (section) {
    var top = section.offsetTop - window.pageYOffset;
    var offset = top - logo.offsetTop;
    
    // If the top edge of the section is behind the logo
    if (top <= logo.offsetTop) {
      // Make sure the section color has its initial height
      currentColor.setAttribute('height', initialHeight);
      // If the logo is still inside the section, fill it with the section color
      var bottom = top + section.clientHeight;
      if (bottom >= logo.offsetTop) {
        currentColor.setAttribute('fill', section.dataset.color);
      }
      
      return;
    }
    
    // If logo collides with the lower section
    if (offset <= logo.clientHeight) {
      nextColor.setAttribute('fill', section.dataset.color);
      currentColor.setAttribute('height', offset);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#logo {
  position: fixed;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: -50px;
}

section {
  height: 100vh
}

#blue {
  background-color: #b4da55;
}
```

```html
<div id="logo">

  <svg height="48" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    
    <path height="48" id="nextColor" d="M5.8 0v36.3h10.7V48l25.6-11.7V0H5.8zm10.5"/>
    
    <path height="48" id="currentColor" y="0" d="M5.8 0v36.3h10.7V48l25.6-11.7V0H5.8zm10.5"/>
 
  </svg>
</div>

<div class="sections">
  <section data-color="#b4da55" id="white"></section>
  <section data-color="#ffffff" id="blue"></section>
  <section data-color="#b4da55" id="white"></section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by [clipping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Clipping_and_masking) the white logo within a rectangle.

Logic is the following:

- green logo is always shown
- whenever the "blue" section overlaps with the logo, move a rectangle so that it covers the overlapped surface (change it's y position and height)
- white logo is clipped within this rectangle, and appears on top of the green logo

Updated snipped below. If what happens is not totally clear to you, you may just move the `rect` definition outside of `clipPath`, this way you will visualize how its position and visibility evolve with the scrolling.

Side note: You may want to [debounce](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function) the scroll event listener, to maintain a good performance in your page.

```js
var logo = document.querySelector('#logo')
    , clipRect = document.querySelector('#clipRect')
    , blueSection = document.querySelector('#blue')

window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {

    // position of the top of the blue section
    var top = blueSection.offsetTop - window.pageYOffset
        // position of the bottom of the blue section
        , bottom = blueSection.offsetTop + blueSection.clientHeight - window.pageYOffset
    
    // offset between top of the logo and top of the blue section
    var offset = top - logo.offsetTop


    if ( offset <= logo.clientHeight && bottom >= logo.offsetTop) {
    // blue section overlaps with the logo

        clipRect.setAttribute('y', Math.max(offset, 0))
        
        clipRect.setAttribute('height', bottom - logo.offsetTop)
    }
    else {
    // blue section does not overlap with the logo
    
        // make sure the clip-path isn't visible
        clipRect.setAttribute('y', 0)
        clipRect.setAttribute('height', 0)
    }
    
})
```

```css
#logo {
  position: fixed;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: -50px;
}

section {
  height: 100vh
}

#blue {
  background-color: #b4da55;
}

#currentColor {
  fill: #b4da55;
}

#nextColor {
  fill: white;
}

/*
following useful only for testing purpose
*/
#clipRect {
  fill: red;
  fill-opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<div id="logo">

  <svg height="48" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <defs>
  <clipPath id="clipping">
    <rect id="clipRect" x="0" y="0" width="48" height="0"></rect>
  </clipPath>
 </defs>
    
    <path height="48" id="currentColor" d="M5.8 0v36.3h10.7V48l25.6-11.7V0H5.8zm10.5"/>
    <path height="48" id="nextColor" d="M5.8 0v36.3h10.7V48l25.6-11.7V0H5.8zm10.5" clip-path="url(#clipping)"/>

     
  </svg>
</div>

<div class="sections">
  <section data-color="#b4da55" id="white"></section>
  <section data-color="#ffffff" id="blue"></section>
  <section data-color="#b4da55" id="white"></section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not using the SVG rectangle shape the way I think that you think it is. To demonstrate this, I changed the `rect`s to `ellipse`s, and then changed the attributes as appropriate, i.e. `y` to `cy`, `width` to `rx`, and `height` to `ry`. The result shows that the shape is, first of all, only showing a portion of the whole shape (the bottom right quarter?) and, secondly, actually squashing the shape when the section border overlays it. You don't see these things in your original example because a quarter of a rectangle is still a rectangle, and a squashed rectangle is also still a rectangle. Thus, what you think is working in your original example actually isn't working. So the problem is not using the path, it's your original code.

If you only want to use rectangles, you can use your original code as is, I suppose, because it *does* produce the desired visual effect. However, if you were only using the rectangle as a proof-of-concept and your real end goal is using a path, then you need a different approach. You might consider using `clipPath`/`clip-path` to "cut" the path into parts as a section border is passing over it, but that would take some significant re-working of your code.

```js
var sections = document.querySelectorAll('section');
var logo = document.querySelector('#logo');
var nextColor = document.querySelector('#nextColor');
var currentColor = document.querySelector('#currentColor');
var initialHeight = logo.clientHeight;
var lastScrollPosition = 0;

// Set current section color
sections.forEach(function (section) {
  var top = section.offsetTop - window.pageYOffset;
  if (top <= logo.offsetTop && (top + section.clientHeight) >= logo.offsetTop) {
    currentColor.setAttribute('fill', section.dataset.color);
  }
});

window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
  sections.forEach(function (section) {
    var top = section.offsetTop - window.pageYOffset;
    var offset = top - logo.offsetTop;
    
    // If the top edge of the section is behind the logo
    if (top <= logo.offsetTop) {
      // Make sure the section color has its initial height
      currentColor.setAttribute('ry', initialHeight);
      // If the logo is still inside the section, fill it with the section color
      var bottom = top + section.clientHeight;
      if (bottom >= logo.offsetTop) {
        currentColor.setAttribute('fill', section.dataset.color);
      }
      
      return;
    }
    
    // If logo collides with the lower section
    if (offset <= logo.clientHeight) {
      nextColor.setAttribute('fill', section.dataset.color);
      currentColor.setAttribute('ry', offset);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#logo {
  position: fixed;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: -50px;
}

section {
  height: 100vh
}

#dark {
  background-color: #2a2a2a;
}
```

```html
<div id="logo">
  <svg height="100" width="100">
    <ellipse id="nextColor" rx="100" ry="100"/>
    <ellipse id="currentColor" cy="0" rx="100" ry="100"/>
  </svg>
</div>

<div class="sections">
  <section data-color="#000000" id="light"></section>
  <section data-color="#ffffff" id="dark"></section>
  <section data-color="#cccccc" id="light2"></section>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot andrew, i think i asked my question wrong, the code with the rect is working, it changes the color fluid. but the second example is a logo i want to use...it uses paths, it does change the color but it jumps instead of slowly replacing it

Comment: I would still maintain that, if I understand your intentions correctly, while it looks like your rect is working, it actually isn't. The rect appears to gradually change from one color to the next as the section border passes over it. However, my circle is essentially exactly the same as your rect, and the circle shows that the shape (whether rect or circle or path) is _not_ having its color slowly replaced. It is actually being duplicated, with one copy "jumping" to the new color immediately and the other maintaining the original color but being distorted shape-wise.